# Acesssing @LocalBean packaged in ejb.jar from app.war

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans-7, ejb-3.1

So I have a classical ear composed out of an jar file with ejb's and a war file.

What should I do in order to make ejb's visible in the war file ?

I am using netbeans for prototyping this , but when i try to access the bean from jsf it is not visible.

Do i have to reference somehow the ejb's in the war on project level ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured it out...while reading some articles.I had to annotate that bean with @Named and 
it was already visible

Also on project level there is a dependency between the war and ejb.jar added just for compile  time by netbeans.